# Having a batch file check its own output?

Tags: maven, command-line, batch-file

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a batch file check itself for a string.

I'm using a batch file to run Maven commands,and I want to check if anything failed by searching for a "FAILURE" string at the end of the script

I know you can `FIND` in other files, but can you have it check the current output on itself, or is the best solution to save the batch file output as a text and then search it?

As an example, if I had a batch file `echo Hello World` it would print `Hello World`, then I would want to search the output for `Hello` and tell me it found the string `Hello`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I like vane's idea to take action upon the return code provided by mvn, but instead of using ERRORLEVEL, I like to use the `||` operator. The commands after `||` are only excecuted if the prior command failed.

```
::initialize error flag to undefined
set "mvnErr="

::run your Maven command and define the error flag if there was an error
call mvn {your arguments here} || set mvnErr=1

::You can now take action if there was an error
if defined mvnErr echo there was a Maven error
```

Comment: It's a bit unwieldy to do this for a larger batch file but definitely nicer than riddling everything with `if errorlevel ...` :-)

Comment: Failure doesn't necessarily mean that it throws any errors though, since it's able to just continue. Or does maven report failures as errors?

Comment: @Johannes - I've never used Maven, but based on what I have read, it should return a positive error code if the build failed as long as you are using version 2.0.9 or later. It seems like that is something you can test yourself easy enough.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by checking the `errorlevel` after each Maven command. For example

```
@ECHO OFF

set hasErrors=0

REM execute maven command here
if not errorlevel 0 set hasErrors=1

REM more batch command and similar checking ...

if %hasErrors%==1 (
    echo print your error info or do whatever
)
```

Comment: Is that something built into Maven? To keep track of `errorlevel`?

Comment: @Johannes The errorlevel checking is not built into maven but setting the errorlevel upon completion of commands executed with `mvn` is. So `mvn` will set errorlevel to something other than 0 if it has an error.

Comment: @Johannes `mvn` will set errorlevel to 1 if there is an error and 0 if there are no errors

Answer (score 2):

Building off of both the 2 previous answers, I think this gives the best of both worlds. The `||` syntax is short and easy to read and the `IF` statement before every command ensure processing only progresses when previous operations were successful.

```
set hasErrors=0
IF %hasErrors%==0 call mvn -f ./mycoservices/pom.xml install || set hasErrors=1
IF %hasErrors%==0 call mvn -f ./mycostatic/pom.xml install || set hasErrors=1
IF %hasErrors%==0 call mvn -f ./mycoweb/pom.xml install || set hasErrors=1
IF %hasErrors%==0 call mvn -f ./mycowebbundle/pom.xml install || set hasErrors=1
```

Comment: Simpler yet: `cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3 && cmd4 || set hasErrors=1`. Use line continuation `^` after each `&&` to make it read better if you want.

Answer (score 0):

why not just exit the batch whenever it fail

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
 echo exit /b %errorlevel%
 exit /b %errorlevel%
)
```